# Finding the Values on both ends of the d3.js Axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

If you have an `xAxis` in d3.js, how to you detemine the smallest and largest values on the `xAxis` axis, considering the user may have translated/zoomed?

```
x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([10,100])
    .range([this.height + this.margin.top, this.margin.top]);

xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x);

zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .x(x)
    .y(y)
    .on('zoom', redraw);

function redraw() {
    svg.select('.x.axis').call(xAxis)
}
```

`x.ticks()` only provides the labels of the ticks which may not be the min/max values of the axis.

Comment: Would you mind providing the code that defines x? xAxis boundaries are defined by the x domain. x(domainUpperBoundary), x(domainLowerBoundary) might provide what you need.

Comment: @JesusRuiz Updated the post with the defination of `x`. Although its domain may be 10 to 100, the user can zoom in such that only data in the domain [50,60] is viewable, the rest are off screen. Wonder if there is a function that is the inverse of `x()`.

Comment: You should be able to call `x.domain()` at any point to get its zoomed/translated domain.